# how to call return values in PythonOperator Airflow?

Tags: python, pandas, workflow, airflow, pipeline

I am new to Airflow and I am practicing a bit, for example I have a function that reads a file (excel) and returns the converted file to DataFrame. My second function is to receive that file and delete null values and return the DF again without null values. So on I have several functions.

My question is that I don't know how to parameterize those functions in PythonOperator so that it receives values from another function

```py
def read_file():
  df = pd.read_excel('EXCEL.xlsx')
  return df

def remove_NULL(df):
  df.dropna(inplace = True)
  return df

.......

with DAG('Example', start_date=datetime(AAAA, MM, DD), schedule_interval='@daily', catchup=False) as dag:

  step1 = PythonOperator(task_id = 'read', python_callable = read_file)

  step2 = PythonOperator(task_id = 'drop', python_callable = remove_NULL)


  step1 >> step2
```

The first step works ok, the second not because I don't know how to call the value returned

Comment: What you are trying to do is called XCOM https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom. Anyway, is not advisable to use XCOM with large objects as dataframes.

Comment: this case is just a Test, but really I don't know how connect the tasks

Comment: @CaioBelfort do you know how can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link to receives the values from another function

```
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py
```